# Google DFP API issue after version update

Tags: google-api, google-dfp

I am facing issue in google DFP api as google updated the API.

We have used Google DFP api version 'v201605' to fetch DFP account data into our site. Now, latest version for this API is 'v201702'. Google had removed api from it's list which we have used.

It is automatically stops to fetch **LineItem** and other services of DFP api which we used to fetch as per below,

```
$user = new DfpUser();
$user->LogDefaults();
$inventoryService = $user->GetService('InventoryService', 'v201605');
$lineItemService = $user->GetService('LineItemService', 'v201605');
```

In Latest version API, Google had completely changed the format and structure of API code.

**We need to re-enable the old API version so our code can work again as before.**

Feeling helpless on this now.

Have anyone faced same kind of issue ?
Looking forward for responses.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the Service like this

```
$dfpServices = new DfpServices();
$session = new DfpSessionBuilder();
...do session handling...

$lineItemService = $dfpServices->get($session, LineItemService::class);
```

At this point all features are the same as before, just wrapped into Classes.